# How to Convert dictionary to json using three arguments

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

Today:

```
Table
address 1     zipcode    city
------------------------------
angel         123        and
candy         321        klj
mandy         874        jk3
```

Goal:

```
object
    1
        address: xxxx
        zipcode: xxxx
        city:    xxxxx
    2
        address: xxxx
        zipcode: xxxx
        city:    xxxxx
    3
        address: xxxx
        zipcode: xxxx
        city:    xxxxx
```

How do you convert it from dictionary to json using c#?

In dictionary, you only can have two arguments

```
    Dictionary<string, string> aa1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    aa1.Add("angel", "123");
    aa1.Add("candy", "321");
    aa1.Add("mandy", "874");

    string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(aa1);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to create a class that represents one row of your table, then create a collection of that class, then serialize.  As it sits now your Dictionary does not even contain all the info you need.  You should post the expected JSON structure if you want any real help

Comment: What is the JSON structure that you are ultimately trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a class which rapresents your entity (row). Something like:

```
class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address 1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "zipcode")]
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use that class in this way:

```
var aa1 = new List<Person>();

aa1.Add(new Person()
{
    Address1 = "angel",
    ZipCode = 123,
    City = "and"
});

aa1.Add(new Person()
{
    Address1 = "candy",
    ZipCode = 321,
    City = "klj"
});

aa1.Add(new Person()
{
    Address1 = "mandy",
    ZipCode = 874,
    City = "jk3"
});
```

And serialize it using:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aa1);
```

which produces this JSON:

```
[  
    {  
        "address 1":"angel",
        "zipcode":123,
        "city":"and"
    },
    {  
        "address 1":"candy",
        "zipcode":321,
        "city":"klj"
    },
    {  
        "address 1":"mandy",
        "zipcode":874,
        "city":"jk3"
    }
]
```

---

**Note on produced JSON**

It's not clear (at least for me) how your JSON should be structured (for example wrapped in an object). This is a way.

Also I assumed that the names of the table columns should be respected. Each column meet each property of the class. Note that the column `address 1` contains a space. C# doesn't allow a property name with a space so I had to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which allows to set a custom property name when serializing an object. `JavaScriptSerializer` has no way to rename a property for serialization outside of writing a custom `JavaScriptConverter` (but that's a different story).

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try please.

```
ar aa1 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dict["address"] = "angel";
dict["zipcode"] = "123";
dict["city"] = "and";

aa1.Add(dict);

dict["address"] = "candy";
dict["zipcode"] = "321";
dict["city"] = "klj";

aa1.Add(dict);

dict["address"] = "mandy";
dict["zipcode"] = "874";
dict["city"] = "jk3";

aa1.Add(dict);

string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(aa1);

Console.WriteLine(myJsonString);
```